# State-of-the-art for embedding scriptable, interactive SVG in Gtk+ applications?

Tags: c, gtk, svg

I'm interested in writing a Gtk application that uses an embedded SVG canvas for graphics, and I'm wondering what the current state-of-the-art is for using SVG in Gtk. I know that it's possible to embed Webkit inside of Gtk, and so that seems like one approach, but I would like to add interactivity to DOM elements in the embedded SVG canvas using C instead of JavaScript, and I'm not sure if the embedded Webkit exposes its DOM APIs to the embedding C context. I'm wondering if there might be a better approach. The last article I was able to find on the subject was from 2004: http://www.osnews.com/story/6460

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`Librsvg`** ([Reference Manual](https://developer-old.gnome.org/rsvg/) / [GitLab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/librsvg))  is the preferred way to draw SVG into GTK+ widgets. However, to my knowledge, it doesn't support any kind of interactivity (only drawing).

Regarding WebKit, it does expose the DOM through [webkit_web_view_get_dom_document](https://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html#webkit-web-view-get-dom-document). Have a look at the WebKitGtk [tests](https://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/WebKit/gtk/tests?rev=67839) for some examples.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that SVG itself is available. But Gtk+ has several Canvas widgets that resemble the idea of SVG (actually, they're not Canvas widgets but Scene Graph widgets). [Clutter](http://www.clutter-project.org/) is one of such widgets.